# mod_security redirect with parameter

Tags: apache, post, mod-security2

Hei folks!

I have a question about mod security:
I want to create a rule which adds a POST parameter when a condition matches:

```
SecRule IP:COUNT "@gt 0" "phase:1,pass,log,id:1111,setvar:ARGS_POST.b=1"
```

Or alternatively, trigger a redirect keeping the POST parameters to the server.
Is that possible? any workarounds?

Above gives:

```
Message: Could not set variable "ARGS_POST.b" as the collection does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **ARGS_POST** is a read-only collection, which can only be used to read POST data from a request body.

Second, what you are trying to accomplish is content injection and you should do these items to get it done,

Set `SecContentInjection On`
Set `SecStreamInBodyInspection On`

Once these two directives are turned on, you would get the REQUEST_BODY POST payload data available in `STREAM_INPUT_BODY` variable.

Then use `@rsub` operator to remove, replace, append data to the REQUEST_BODY.

Please try in these lines and let me know how it goes.

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: Thanks @daniel, I've mentioned ARGS_POST.b=1 as an example (I know its read only). as for the rest, I really appreciate your assistance I'll let you know how it goes as soon as I get to test it.